# Forcing user to fill some sharepoint item field when trying to set other field on edit form

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepointfoundation2010

How to force user to fill some field in edit form when trying to update other choice field to specific value in same sharepoint list item.

Answer (score 0):

I would implement a client side script to implement the logic you need via the xslt style sheet in the edit form.

And Also a server side event handler to make sure that even if the client side logic is overridden you still validate the data on the server. throwing an exception if not valid for instance.

Answer (score 0):

I resover that problem by using list "Validation settings" with rule

```
=IF([Stan przetargu]="oferowanie";IF(LogotecProj<>"";TRUE;FALSE);TRUE)
```